# Designer error: frameworkName cannot be an empty string

Tags: android

I am trying to make a imageview but when running I find this problemme (Error:. (7, 17) Resource id can not Be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@ + id /')) in this line: android: id = "@ + id /">

Comment: Please give some more information about what you are trying to do and what is stopping you from doing it. That is not clear right now.

Comment: I am trying to follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgbGeOIPu8w EVER after the execution I find this problem   (Error:. (7, 17) Resource id can not Be an empty string (at 'id' with value '@ + id /'))

Comment: Why did you tag the question with "ios" while it is clearly an android related question?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are whitespaces which are not allowed! Not sure if its just a copy and paste error. Here with underscroe to show you the white spaces.

   android: id = "@_+*id*/"
2. you dont define any id. you have to add an name after `@+id/` like:

   android:id="@+id/my_id"